# input box value getting double interger

Tags: vba, excel

I have an inputbox in which I usually enter the value but when I am entering the numbers from 1- 9 it is taking as 10-90 as I have given the condition that if the inputbox value is greater than 50 display a error message.

This I came to know when I entered no 6 and it displayed the error message. When I checked the input value in the code it is still 1 -9.

What might be the error?

```
inp = InputBox("enter turning angle")

'textbox 1 value is 50
If inp < Sheets("Four Bar").TextBox1.Value Or inp = Sheets("Four Bar").TextBox1.Value Then
    ''my code ''
Else
    MsgBox "Max inner wheel angle is" & " " & Sheets("Four Bar").TextBox1.Value
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

**UNTESTED:**

```
Dim inp As Long
inp = Application.InputBox(prompt:="enter turning angle", Type:=1)

'textbox 1 value is 50
If inp < CLng(Sheets("Four Bar").TextBox1.Value) Or inp = CLng(Sheets("Four Bar").TextBox1.Value) Then
    ''my code ''
Else
    MsgBox "Max inner wheel angle is" & " " & Sheets("Four Bar").TextBox1.Value
End If
```

just to insure we are dealing with **numbers**

Comment: u have used type =1 what does that mean... is that mean the single digit no..?? if so then how can I give 10 to 50 no's ..

Comment: I am getting an error in the code... if no values are entered in the input box it should show that no values are entered..

Comment: i have coded it like 
if inp<> " " then 
msgbox " no values entered"
else
'my code'